# Function not looping through all the values and stopping after first value in the loop

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, for-loop

I am new to python so sorry if I'm not clear. I am trying to create a loop to get moving average of costs for different products. I have a data-set which has over 55000 products(my_product_id) and their cost for every month since 2019-01-01. I am trying to create a function to get moving average of the costs in the most recent 3 months. So far I have written this function which works but only runs for one product and stops the loop after that. I need to be able to run this function over all unique product ids in the column. This is what my data-set looks like

[image]

```
def abc(df_189):
    dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['my_product_id', 'Cost'])
    my_products = df_189.my_product_id.unique()
    for i in my_products:
        df_test = df_189[df_189.my_product_id == i]
        
        Grouped=df_test.groupby('date')
        
        GetWeightAvg=lambda g: np.average(g['cost'], weights=g['quantity'])
        
        pr=Grouped.apply(GetWeightAvg).sort_index(ascending=False).head(3).mean()
        
        dfObj = dfObj.append({'my_product_id': i, 'Cost': pr}, ignore_index=True)
        return dfObj
```

This returns a Dataframe of just one row of the first product ID so its working right but stopping after the first product.

Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `return` out of the loop like this:

```
def abc(df_189):
    dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['my_product_id', 'Cost'])
    my_products = df_189.my_product_id.unique()
    for i in my_products:
        df_test = df_189[df_189.my_product_id == i]
        
        Grouped=df_test.groupby('date')
        
        GetWeightAvg=lambda g: np.average(g['cost'], weights=g['quantity'])
        
        pr=Grouped.apply(GetWeightAvg).sort_index(ascending=False).head(3).mean()
        
        dfObj = dfObj.append({'my_product_id': i, 'Cost': pr}, ignore_index=True)
    return dfObj
```